# Stripe: Registered webhook but still getting "Not a Valid URL" error

Tags: swift, heroku, stripe-payments, webhooks, swift5

I seem to be running into an error each time I try to make a payment transaction where Stripe declines the operation by saying "Not a valid URL". The client-side is in Swift, while the server is in Python, deployed on Heroku.

A suggestion I saw on another post was to register my server webhook with my Stripe account, which I did, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

For reference, here is my `createPaymentIntent` function:

```
func createPaymentIntent(dict: [String:Any]) {
        let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("create-payment-intent")
        let params = dict
        let jsondata = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params)
        var clientSecretOut = ""
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = jsondata
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
          guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            response.statusCode == 200,
            let data = data,
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any],
            let clientSecret = json["clientSecret"] as? String else {
                let message = error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to decode response from server."
                print("Error: ", message)
                return
          }
            clientSecretOut = clientSecret
            print("client out inside: ", clientSecretOut)
            self?.clientSecretFinal = clientSecret
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

And here is the place where the error seems to be called– my `didCreatePaymentResultFunction`:

```
    func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didCreatePaymentResult paymentResult: STPPaymentResult, completion: @escaping STPPaymentStatusBlock) {
        
        let paymentIntentParams = STPPaymentIntentParams(clientSecret: self.clientSecretFinal)
        paymentIntentParams.configure(with: paymentResult)
        paymentIntentParams.returnURL = "meURLStripeTest://"
        
        STPPaymentHandler.shared().confirmPayment(withParams: paymentIntentParams, authenticationContext: paymentContext) { status, paymentIntent, error in
            switch status {
            case .succeeded:
                print("success")
                completion(.success, nil)
            case .failed:
                print("cant", error)
                completion(.error, error)
            case .canceled:
                completion(.userCancellation, nil)
            @unknown default:
                completion(.error, nil)
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line:

`paymentIntentParams.returnURL = "meURLStripeTest://"`

The `returnURL` has to be a [valid URL or application URI scheme](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-return_url), in your case it's neither. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app) on how to create an application URI scheme for your app.

Comment: I tried that by following the link you gave, but Stripe still gives me a "Not a valid URL" error. Weird thing is that when I use that url on Safari in the simulator, it works. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @GurkarnGoindi did you find any solution to this? I am facing same issue.